# Php - character returned by file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents, void

i'm using file_get_contents to retrieve the content of external webpages and then i log the received content into a txt file.

The problem is i've founded some void in the middle of the page, and since that part of page is a human written text i exclude void is really present in the page.

So i've an output like this:

```
Lorem ipsum void sit avoidet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor
```

So which characters may be returned as "void" with file_get_contents?

Thanks a lot

Comment: PHP file_get_content will not change anything, are you sure?

Comment: What is the input that results in that output?